# grep unable to locate string when executing from python

Tags: python, bash

Edit: I use Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS and python 3.8.5

I got a bigger project where there are unused translation keys. I wrote a shell script to do this job. I exported some of the code to 2 testing files to narrow down on the weird behaviour. I am able to reproduce the bug but I fail to understand why it happens.

```
if sudo grep -r --include=\*.{js,html,json} --exclude-dir={node_modules,locale} 404_custom_error ../myreactproject/
then
    echo 'found'
else
    echo 'not found'
fi
```

If I run it via the terminal, it gets found.

```
import os
import subprocess

os.system("./testing.sh")
subprocess.call(['sh', 'testing.sh'])
```

But when I execute it from a python file, it gets a 'not found'.

```
os.getcmd() -> /home/{name}/projects/translation-cleaner
echo $PWD   -> /home/{name}/projects/translation-cleaner
```

Note: The python file and shell script are in the same directory. The other project is in /home/{name}/projects/myreactproject.

That specific key is being found in ../myreactproject/src/views/Pages/Page404/Page404Admin.js:

Comment: All shells are different (see the description of the "shell" tag you attached to your question) and each implements a different programming language, even if many of them are very similar. So, please, tag this with the actual shell you're using!

Comment: I am using bash shell. I was unaware that there are differences between shells. I guess python uses it's own kind of shell that is different from bash shell. In that case, I"ll look into the difference of shells this weekend. I am new to Linux. Tyvm.

Comment: Python doesn't use its own shell, it just does as its told: `subprocess.call(['sh', 'testing.sh'])`. `sh` is not `bash`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have 2 solutions but I have not tested them before on my previous Windows 10 machine since I migrated now fully to linx:

The proper one:

```
subprocess.call(['bash', './testing.sh'])
```

The dirty one:
I had to remove all brackets from my shell script. so my grep command looks like this:

```
grep -qr --include=*.js --include=*.html --include=*.json --exclude-dir=node_modules --exclude-dir=locale 404_custom_error ../myreactproject/;
```

Comment: When you run it from the terminal, are you using `./testing.sh` or `sh testing.sh`?

Comment: I did run ./testing.sh. I was unaware that there was an sh command. I'll also look into that this weekend :)

Comment: If you substitute last line of your Python script with `subprocess.call(['bash', 'testing.sh'])` using the bash script with curly braces it should work again.

Comment: Sorry dariofac for not answering anytime sooner but that did work. It seems I cannot mark your comment as the answer but I'll edit the answer above this one.